# Sorting elements of model depending upon habtm association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model, associations

I have to models named attachments and users associated by has_and_belongs_to_many. now i have to find all attachments sorted in such a way that attachments having association will be displayed first and then those with no association. How can i do this?

Comment: Re-phrase your question. It's not clear as to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One simple and relatively efficient way to do this would be to add a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast) to your `Attachment` model. The counter cache would store and keep up-to-date the number of associations in a column on your `attachments` table, so you could do `Attachment.order( 'user_attachments_count DESC' )`.

Unfortunately HABTM does not support counter cache, so you would have to pop up a "middle-man" model between the two others just to get access to the join table.

Another way (yet with poor performance) is to simply use :

```
 @attachments = Attachment.includes(:users)
 @sorted      = @attachments.sort_by {|r| r.to_a.size }.reverse!
```

Well, if it doesn't fit, you can always start sweating over a SQL query...